# Eigenvalues of a $3 \times 3$ Rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that the eigenvalues of a rotation matrix are, $1$ and complex conjugates of the form $e^{i \theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$.

$i$ is the square root of $-1$ and $\theta$ is the angle

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem and what you've tried?

Comment: A rotation does not change the shape you are rotating. Meaning that the original and image are congruent shapes. That translates into eigenvalues that have an absolute value of 1. In that sense, it doesn't surprise me the kind of eigenvalues you found: All their absolute values are 1. I am not implying a proof here, but a mere confirmation that your eigenvalues shouldn't come as a surprise here.

Comment: A rotation in the $xy$-plane? Such that $z$ remains constant?

Answer (score 2):

By a $3\times 3$ rotation matrix, one usually means an element of $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$, ie. an orthogonal matrix of determinant $+1$.

Suppose $A$ is such a matrix, then we show that $1$ is an eigen-value of$A$ : Consider
$$
det(A-I) = det[(A-I)^t] = det(A^t - I) = det(A)det(A^t-I) = det(I - A) = -det(A-I)
$$
Hence, $det(A-I) = 0$, and let $v$ be the eigen-vector associated to $1$.

Restrict $A$ to the subspace $\{v\}^{\perp}$. This subspace is invariant, and so the restriction of $A$ is a $2\times 2$ special orthogonal matrix (appropriately viewed). Every such matrix looks like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In particular, its eigen values are $e^{\pm i\theta}$